# Handling Multibyte characters in php

Tags: php, internationalization

Am working on php based mime parser. If the body contains string like `Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn` we see that It is getting converted into `IÃ±tÃ«rnÃ¢tiÃ´nÃ lizÃ¦tiÃ¸n`. Can somebody suggest how to handle (what functions) for such string ?

So we are doing the following

1. Using Zend Library connecting to the IMAP server

   ```
   mail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap($params);
   ```
2. Read the message using

   ```
   $message = $mail->getMessage($i);
   ```

   in the loop.
3. When we print the `$message` we see the string e.g. `Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn` printed as `IÃ±tÃ«rnÃ¢tiÃ´nÃ lizÃ¦tiÃ¸n`.

What I need is if there is someway by which we can retain the original string? And this is just one example we may run into other multi-byte characters, so what to know how we handle this generically?

Comment: Could you show the code that's creating the problem? Have you looked at PHP's [multibyte functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php)?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are doing, but you should look at the [`mb_*` functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php).

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php

Comment: As for your particular problem: I don't know the Zend class for this, but you either need to look at the mail header what encoding the mail is in, then convert it as necessary, or you need to configure the Zend class to automatically convert the encoding of the mail to your desired encoding. Either way, you first need to know what your desired encoding is!

Answer (score 0):

There's no specific *function* for that, you simply need to treat the string in the encoding it's in. A string is just a blob of bytes, it gets turned into characters by whatever is *interpreting* those bytes as text. And that something needs to use the correct encoding for that, otherwise those bytes are not interpreted as the characters they were supposed to be. See [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) for a rundown of the common pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the comment, you can use php mb_* functions to work with multibyte characters. Here is just an example to detect the encoding of a string:

```
$s="Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn";
echo mb_detect_encoding($s);  //UTF-8
```

then you can work with this, use utf8_decode($s) or any mb_ functions to convert the string to your wished encoding.

Comment: `mb_detect_encoding` is *mostly* useless, because it's practically impossible to accurately detect unknown encodings. *Know* what encoding your text is (supposed to be) in, don't guess.